# pure functional programming: how to add an element to a list?

Tags: functional-programming

In pure functional programming, we do not modify any arguments of a function. Then, how can we design a function that adds an element to its argument, a list? For example, `function list add (elem, list)`. This question is similar to this thread: [Functional programming: state vs. reassignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353912/functional-programming-state-vs-reassignment/355040#355040) .

My guess solution is to **deep-copy** the input list and then to use some destructive operations like `append` to manipulate the new one. Am I right?

**appending**

I copy the following code from a graph-copy algorithm:

```
// in Node
public Node deepCopy(Map<Node, Node> isomorphism) {
    Node copy = isomorphism.get(this);
    if (copy == null) {
        copy = new Node();
        isomorphism.put(this, copy);
        for (Node connection: connections) {
            copy.connections.add(connection.deepCopy(isomorphism));
        }
    }
    return copy;
}
```

To deep-copy a graph, one must track every node that is being copied. In the universe, we use the `isomorphism` argument to do that. I think the only way to make a pure functional version of this `deepCopy` operation is to return not only the variable `copy` but also a flag indicating whether the returned node is new one. Right?

Comment: @hammar That's what I actually concerned: such new object creation operations may be very expensive.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to return a new list with the element added.

However, this doesn't have to require a deep copy. Functional languages typically feature [persistent data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) which allow parts of the structure to be shared between versions, so that you can e.g. prepend an element to a list in O(1) time.

Answer (score 1):

You would write a function to build a NEW list (in this case, one with the new element added to the old list) & return that.

Comment: +1. Most functional languages use a list structure where adding to one end (usually the head) is trivial.  Note that if you can't modify anything, there's no need to make a copy of the rest, deep or otherwise. Multiple lists can share the same sublist.